# TortoiseHg + MQ: how to customize the default name for new patches?

Tags: tortoisehg

In TortoiseHg, when creating a new patch with the QNew button, the patch name is defaulted to date time and rev:

[image]

Is there a way of specifying some other default, using a custom template (for example, to include the repository name and the rev, without the date)?